# Передача данных с помощью Ajax в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Не знаю где допустил ошибку. Не получается передать данные через Ajax в *PHP*-файл.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <?
    while ($news = $news_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        $NewsCategoryID = $news['NewsCategoryID'];
        echo '<li class=""><a id="NewsCategoryID onclick="myFunction()" href="#' . $news['NewsCategoryID'] . '" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">' . $news['NewsCategoryTitle'] . '</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<table class="table table-striped" id="content"></table>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var NewsCategoryID = '<?echo $NewsCategoryID?>'
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_news.php",
            data: NewsCategoryID, 
            dataType: "text",
            timeout: 30000,
            async: false,
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log('Ошибка!' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText); 
            },
            success: function(a) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = a;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Что есть `var NewsCategoryID = '<?echo $NewsCategoryID?>'`? P.S. Поставьте после объявления точку с запятой.

Comment: 1. Смесь PHP и HTML и выглядит мрачно, и плоха с точки зрения архитектуры, и ошибок в ней наделать можно немало. Стоит использовать фреймворк или что-то ещё для передачи полученных в модели данных во View. 2. JS скрипты должны быть вынесены в отдельные файлы, и уж тем более в них не должны быть ни намёка на PHP. Думаю, после приведения проекта в корректный вид многие ошибки и проблемы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогло. Скрипт куда летит запрос работает, но сам запрос не долетает до скрипта. Внутри тэга table должен приходить ответ из скрипта ajax_news.php , в ответе правильные тэги <tr>  и <td>

Comment: А, да: ещё не стоит экономить на пробелах и переводах строк. За `async: false`, кстати, обычно полагается расстрел на месте. А раз используется _jQuery_, то и конструкции в стиле `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML` использовать смысла нет.

Comment: Я вам настойчиво предлагаю взять и переделать всё с нуля, воспользовавшись приличной архитектурой проекта. Негоже такую кашу из PHP, HTML и JS делать. А по поводу вашего вопроса: строка должна выглядеть примерно так: `data: { "NewsCategoryID" : NewsCategoryID }, `

Comment: Чего прилипли со своими моделями. Может у человека своя религия

Comment: где вы смотрели ответ? в _success_ функцию вы попадаете?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так

`data: {
        "NewsCategoryID":NewsCategoryID
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var NewsCategoryID = '<?=$NewsCategoryID;?>';

echo "<li class=''><a id='NewsCategoryID' onclick='myFunction()' href='#{$news['NewsCategoryID']}' data-toggle='tab' aria-expanded='true'>{$news['NewsCategoryTitle']}</a></li>";
```

Проверь еще раз пунктуацию и далее отладчиком смотри, что куда уходит и приходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решил не мучится и сделать по другому

```html
<script>
  function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("NewsCategoryID").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("NewsCategoryID").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_news.php?NewsCategoryID=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
</script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <? while ($news=$ news_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){ $NewsCategoryID = $news['NewsCategoryID']; echo '
  <li class=""><a onclick="showUser('.$NewsCategoryID.');" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">'.$news['NewsCategoryTitle'].'</a>
  </li>'; } ?>
</ul>
<table class="table table-striped" id="NewsCategoryID">

</table>
```